# Enable x-axis label for the last chart selected

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have common x axis for all 3 charts. Want to show X-axis label only for the last chart selected. I wouldn't know exactly how many chart I would select. So this has to be dynamic.

I tried below:
I initially disable x-axis label for all charts. Need to enable x-axis label only for the last chart selected(Which would be the bottom most chart).

```
 document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input').forEach(function(checkbox) {
 checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 const id = e.target.dataset.id,
 checked = e.target.checked,
 checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input:checked').length,
 node = document.querySelector(`#chart${id}`);

 const chartEps = [
    chartEp1,
    chartEp2,
    chartEp3,
  ] 
  console.log("id", id)   
  //chartEps[id].xAxis[0].options.labels.enabled = true

  // The ID has to be the id of last chart selected. So that only for last chart xAxis label is enabled.   
  chartEps[id].update({ 
  labels: {
     enabled: true
 },
 });
```

Please see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhLt6a01/8/

Instead of dynamic x axis label, I also tried setting empty chart with x axis which need to shown at all times at the bottom (commented code at the bottom of fiddle).

But couldn't get both options to work. I would really appreciate If I could get any help on this.

Comment: One way is to set `chart.xAxis[0].options.labels.enabled =  ...(use your criterion)` in the `forEach` loop

Comment: Another is in the `update` call, set the option `xAxis:{labels: {enabled: ...}}`, but at the top level of the options, outside the `chart: {...}` entry

Comment: Thank you. When I try chartEps[id].xAxis[0].options.labels.enabled = true as I have edited above, Says properties of undefined (reading xAxis).

Comment: What's different from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/348xpwvn/)?

Comment: Sorry dint update the fiddle link. Updated now.

Comment: I think you should parse the id and it's -1 from id to index `chartEps[parseInt(id)-1].` ... (actually you have to parse it just to do -1, otherwise it would've been fine, but it updated the wrong chart)

Comment: I have edited fiddle as per suggestion (have set option outside chart). But both chart2 and chart3 gets x-axis label. Only last chart selected should get x axis label. I would appreciate if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otyz9r8b/) - some changes: the `load` event was triggered when each chart loaded, so there were 3 `change` installed for each checkbox; then the axis update is done in the `forEach` loop, so the same criterion is applied for all charts and I put in a `selected` array to keep track on which checkbox is selected - you can do that with dom queries also

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks a lot. If you could add it as a answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically enable/disable the labels, in the update call, set the option [`xAxis`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis), but (somehow unexpectedly) it should be at the top level of the options object, at the same level as [`chart`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart):

```js
Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart, i) {
  chart.update({
     chart: {
        height: height / checkedCheckboxes
     },
     xAxis:{
        labels: {
           enabled: ...your boolean criterion here for chart i... 
        }
     }
  });
});
```

For the particular case when you want to enable the axis only for the last shown chart I'd use something on lines of

```js
{enabled: selected[i] && selected.indexOf(true, i+1) === -1}
```

where `selected` is an array that keeps track on selected checkboxes, that is equivalent to shown charts. Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otyz9r8b/) for a modified version of your original code.

Comment: kindly let me know if you have any idea on this. xAxis label does not get enabled when I use if condition on chart definition.  Thanks again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179404/xaxis-label-is-not-enabled-while-using-if-condition-on-chart-definition

Comment: In the above link, any chart selected returns 'selected.indexOf(true, i+1)', as -1. Which makes enabled as true when 'selected[i]' is also true. But when I click chart5, 'selected.indexOf(true, i+1)'  returns 4 and selected[i] is undefined.