# xAxis label is not enabled while using if condition on chart definition

Tags: javascript

I display multiple charts in a single page based on checkbox selected. Last chart selected will have xAxis label enabled (as I have common xAxis for all charts). Working Fiddle of the same: https://jsfiddle.net/otyz9r8b/

Below fiddle has 5 charts in total. I have used condition on all charts.

```
 Chart1 chart2, chart3 gets displayed fine as it satisfies if condition. 
 chart4 does not get displayed as it does not satisfy condition. 
 Problem is with chart5. It satisfies if condition and gets displayed. But does not have xAxis label enabled
```

When I click on chart5, it satisfies condition and gets displayed. But xAxis label does not get enabled.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmv5ez8n/31/

In the above link, any chart selected returns 'selected.indexOf(true, i+1)', as -1 and 'selected[i]' as true. Which makes xAxis label enabled for that particular chart. But when I click chart5, 'selected.indexOf(true, i+1)' returns 4 and selected[i] is undefined.

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that in your example fiddle  `chart4` is not created (the condition of `(chart4 ==="chart4"){` is not fulfilled), so there are only 4 charts but 5 checkboxes and 5 divs. This implies that you have to devise a method to get from the chart to the checkbox - up to now it used the index of the chart in `Highcharts.charts` + 1, but that doesn't hold if not all checkboxes ids have a corresponding chart.

Comment: There are several ways to do that. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se8jah1o/1/) I added an `id` key to the chart initialization options and retrieved it with `chart.options.id`. I also discovered an interesting fact about highcharts `load` event - that it is fired synchronously - I might add that in an answer later if it's not included in other answers here.

Comment: This was of real help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Would "load event - firing synchronously" help in reducing time to load charts?

Comment: No, it's an unexpected behavior (not to say a blunder) - if the chart doesn't depend on external resources, the "load" event fires in the same thread, immediately after the chart was created with `Highcharts.chart`, it doesn't wait for all charts to be created and then fire for each one.

Comment: If you're not happy with load times, maybe the problem is somewhere else than highcharts, it seems pretty fast to me https://jsfiddle.net/2b0hc5rg/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. That seems pretty fast. Let me check where I am going wrong.

Comment: Less the number of charts that meets 'if' condition, load time gets better in my case. I am now checking on how I parse data. Kindly let me know if you have any input on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74204351/parsing-file-improve-load-time

Comment: Also, if you could add this as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results from the fact that you have a "dynamic" number of charts created. In your code it's
the variables like `chart4`, but I presume in production code it's
some kind of user input.

The fiddle in the comments seems to solve the
problem, and I wouldn't have written this answer except for the
fact that I discovered an unusual behavior of Highcharts (I consider
reporting it as a bug or at least checking if it is the intended behavior) that might be encountered by other users.

#### Are all charts loaded? - the perils of chart `load` event handler

Your code tries to determine when all charts are loaded, so it may install
some event drivers. It does so, naturally, by counting the number
of times the `load` event was fired and comparing it to the number of charts
as `Highcharts.charts.length`:

```js
let nLoaded = 0;
Highcharts.setOptions({
   chart: {
      events: {
         load() {     
            nLoaded++;
            if(nLoaded === Highcharts.charts.length){
               onAllLoaded();
            }
         }
      }
   },//.....
});
```

There are of course ways to know the number of charts, even if
it depends on user input, without using Highcharts. Still, this
seems the simplest and most natural way to do it, and more practical
also since it is the same regardless of the way user data is structured.

Except it doesn't work: the condition `nLoaded === Highcharts.charts.length`
is true for all 4 times the function is called.

This happens because the strange feature of Highcharts that
**the `load` event is called synchronously on the main thread** (see
[Jake Archibald](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)'s
video if you haven't already). This actually happens only if there
are no external resources to be loaded by the chart.

In the case of your code, things go this way: a chart is created
by a call to `Highcarts.chart`, it does all its initialization
and immediately after calls `load`. At this point there is
only one chart defined, so indeed `Highcharts.charts.length` is 1.
As so on, for 2, 3, 4.

Besides this particular application, this behavior may result
in bloated execution if the load handlers do some time-consuming
computations. The execution of event handlers is deferred to a
task queue for all event handlers I encountered. And it is
deferred in Highcharts too, *if the chart requires external resources*.

The solution I found for this problem is to defer the action
explicitly through a call to `setTimeout`:

```js
let nLoaded = 0;
Highcharts.setOptions({
   chart: {
      events: {
         load() {     
            setTimeout(chartLoaded, 0);
         }
      }
   },//.....
});
function chartLoaded(){
   nLoaded++;
   if(nLoaded === Highcharts.charts.length){
      onAllLoaded();
   }
}
```

Full code:

```js
var chart123 = "chart123"
var chart4 = "chart44"
var chart5 = "chart5"

const height = 690;
let  nLoaded = 0;

// To have xAxis label enabled for the last chart selected.
function updateCharts(){
    const selected = Highcharts.charts.map(chart=>document.querySelector(`#checkbox${chart.options.id}`).checked);
    
    const checkedCheckboxes = selected.filter(x=>x).length; // counts true values in selected
    const lastSelected = selected.lastIndexOf(true); // the last index of true
    Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart, i) {
        chart.update({
            chart: {
                height: height / checkedCheckboxes
            },
            xAxis:{
                labels: {
                    enabled: i === lastSelected
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function onAllLoaded(){
    updateCharts(); // sets the axis for the first one too.
    document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input').forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            const id = e.target.dataset.id,
                checked = e.target.checked,
                node = document.querySelector(`#chart${id}`);
            if (checked) {
                node.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                node.style.display = 'none';
            }
            updateCharts();
        });
    });
    
}

function chartLoaded(){
    nLoaded++;
    if(nLoaded === Highcharts.charts.length){
        onAllLoaded();
    }
}

// common for all charts
Highcharts.setOptions({
    
    chart: {
        events: {
            load() {
                setTimeout(chartLoaded, 0);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    // x axis
    "xAxis": {
        categories: ['jan', 'mar', 'may', 'jul', 'sep', 'nov'],
    },
    yAxis: [{
        tickAmount: 7,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 2,
    }],
    
    series: [{
    }],
});


// We have 5 charts below. I have 40 of them in my real code.
if(chart123 ==="chart123"){
    var chartEp1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
        chart: {
            height: height
        },
        id: 1,
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'grey',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            connectNulls: true,
            data: [2, 5, 2, 3, 6]
        }]
    });
    
    var chartEp2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
        id: 2,
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'grey',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            connectNulls: true,
            data: [2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7]
        }]
    });
    
    var chartEp3 =  Highcharts.chart('chart3', {
        id: 3,
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'grey',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            connectNulls: true,
            data: [2, 5, 2, 3,8]
        }]
    });
}

if(chart4 ==="chart4"){
    var chartEp4=  Highcharts.chart('chart4', {
        id: 4,
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: '#336699',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            connectNulls: true,
            data: [2, 5, 2, 3,8]
        }]
    });
}

if(chart5 ==="chart5"){
    var chartEp6 =  Highcharts.chart('chart5', {
        id: 5,
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'grey',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            connectNulls: true,
            data: [20000, 50000, 2, 3,8]
        }]
    });
}
```

```css
#container {
    height: 690px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chart1 {
    display: block;
}
#chart2 {
  display: none;
}
#chart3 {
  display: none;
}

#chart4, #chart5 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" data-id=1 checked=true>
    <label for="checkbox1">chart1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" data-id=2>
    <label for="checkbox2">chart2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" data-id=3>
    <label for="checkbox3">chart3</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" data-id=4>
    <label for="checkbox4">chart4</label>    
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" data-id=5>
    <label for="checkbox5">chart5</label> 
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <div id="chart2"></div>
  <div id="chart3"></div>
 <div id="chart4"></div> 
 <div id="chart5"></div> 
</div>
```