# Parsing file - Improve load time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

May I know If I could parse differently, so that performance and load time can be improved. I deal with file size that is in MBs.

My file with multiple objects is parsed as below:

- I display multiple graphs in a single page.
- 'chart1' to 'chart5' arrays are used for each graph's Y-axis.
- 'xAxisTime' array is used for x-axis (common x-axis for all graphs).
- eg: I get 50000 values in each array (chart1, chart2...xAxisTime).

  ```
   data = fileWithMultipleObjects;
   objects= data.split('\n');
   for (var i= 0; i < objects.length - 2; i++) {
       var obj = JSON.parse(objects[i])

       if (obj.type=== "A") {
           chart1.push(obj.c1)
           chart2.push(obj.c2)
       }
       else {
           chart1.push(null)
           chart2.push(null)
       }  
       if (obj.type=== "B") {
           chart3.push(obj.c3)
           chart4.push(obj.c4)      
           chart5.push(obj.c5)                
       }
       else {
           chart3.push(null)
           chart4.push(null)   
           chart5.push(null)                           
       }         
       //common for all charts - xAxis data
       if (obj.date === undefined) {
           obj.date = null
       }

       if (obj.date!== null) {  
           var date= obj.date          
           xAxisTime.push(date)
       }
  ```

  }

Reason for pushing null values when no data:

- I need to show all 5 graphs in line with the time the job was run.
- Also, this helps me use "this.point.y" (var index = this.point.y), which helps me display tooltips on plotline. Fiddle showing tooltip(when clicked on green line) with "this.point.y" :https://jsfiddle.net/xqb0cn5r/4/

This is how my graphs look. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgpL1w3t/. Only charts that meets if condition are rendered. chart1 and chart5 are rendered in this case. Thank you.

Edited:

```
Below is the data structure of my file:

{"C1":55.77,"C2":11367.25,"type":"A","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.236"}
{"C3":55.77,"C4":11367.25,"type":"B","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.236","C5":445.21}
{"C1":55.77,"C2":11367.25,"type":"A","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.236"}
{"C1":55.77,"C2":11367.25,"type":"A","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.240"}
{"C3":55.77,"C4":11367.25,"type":"B","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.250","C5:445.25}
{"C3":55.77,"C4":11367.25,"type":"B","date":"10/24/2022 12:05:37.275","C5":445.26}
```

I display like 8 to 10 charts in real scenario with around 50000 points each. Common x-axis for all. Out of 50000, only 2000 to 4000 are real data, remaining are all null values. I push null, so that I can keep graphs in line with the whole time(x-axis) the job was run.

Right now, it takes time to load charts. As so much data to parse and load. I believe performance can be be improved if my data is parsed differently for the same scenario. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Performing single json parse as below:

```
    var convertStringToJsonFormat= "[" + data.split('\n').join(", ")
    JsonFormat = convertStringToJsonFormat.slice(0, -2);
    JsonFormat = JsonFormat + "]"     
    data = JSON.parse(JsonFormat)
```

Comment: Hi @Sarahrb, Could you describe your problem in more detail? Do you want to increase the performance of parsing a text file? What is your data structure (fileWithMultipleObjects variable)?

Comment: Please see details under edited. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could transform your text into a single json string something like this `"["+data.split("\n").join(",")+"]"`and perform a single `JSON.parse()`. Other than this, you are processing your data linearly, without recursion and without complex code invocations. It can be written more succintly, but I doubt it can be much more performance improved.

Comment: @PA Thank you for the input. I performed single json parse as mentioned (pls see under edited). Though it is a better way to parse, I do not see improvement in performance.

Comment: @PA's idea is great, it should be faster since `JSON.parse` is compiled. What goes in favor of line-by-line compilation is the fact that it incorporates some information about the data being parsed. I created a generator of simulated data (please let me know how I can make it more realistic) and tested the two variants [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bvgm9px/). It turns out that it depends on the engine (browser, node) being used, but **in all cases data parsing takes very little time **, typically less than 100ms for 100k data parsed, so it seems it's not the parsing that impacts performance.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to be the `null` data, see https://jsfiddle.net/2s6x39w5/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/2b0hc5rg/1/

Comment: So it may have something to do with how data is processed from parsing to charting -- I presume that not all 50k data points make it verbatim to the charts.

Comment: @kikon Thanks a lot for the time and fiddle shared.  I tried for 2000000 data as I would be dealing in MBs. Seems 'line by line JSON parse' would be better choice in my case. 'Array(n)  --- line-by-line parse' seems the most efficient.

Comment: Yes, all 50k point make it to each chart. Any suggestions on if I should be filtering some data? And I noticed that usage of aftersetextremes is one of the main reason why load time is high. Since dataset is heavy. 50000 points in 8 to 10 charts takes time to recalculate extremes on each of them. Fiddle with aftersetextremes: https://jsfiddle.net/xgpL1w3t/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249104/discussion-between-kikon-and-sarahrb).

Comment: @Sarahrb, Please check the data-grouping: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping and the boost features: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module They are both designed for increasing performance. Also, I see that you create three charts at the beginning even if only one chart is selected. You should create a chart for the first time only if it is visible.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for your suggestions. I will look into data grouping and check  how I can create chart only when selected. I am using boost module already.